# Extract pieces from URL

Tags: url, extract, preg-match-all

I need to extract pieces from a URL and I am trying to learn preg_match_all().

```
The output in a PHP variable:
$content = 'http://www.domain.com/folder1/firstname_lastname.jpg';

Here is my attempt:
preg_match_all('/http://(.*?).jpg/s', $content, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $out[0][0] . "\n";
```

Matching the URL is not easy.
I need to pick out from:
hxxp://www.domain.com/folder1/firstname_lastname.jpg

the following: "www.domain.com" and "folder1" and "firstname_lastname"

Could I get one preg_match_all() for each example?
Thanks in advance.

I like to learn by example and trial and error.
He he... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these:

https://www.php.net/parse_url

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

To get constituent parts of a URL and query string.